# Return unfiltered list if filter function results in empty list

Tags: scala

How do I return the original, unfiltered list if calling `filter` on it returns an empty list and return the filtered list otherwise?

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
scala> l.filter(_ == 4)
res1: List[Int] = List() // would like this to be List(1,2,3)
scala> l.filter(_ == 3)
res: List[Int] = List(3) // want to maintain this behavior
```

Comment: you're asking if the filter returns nothing you want to default to the original array?

Comment: Something like that? val result = list.filter(_ == 4) match {
  case List() => list;
  case x => x
}

Comment: @BjörnJacobs yes that's what I'm looking for. I was hoping for a less verbose solution but that works just fine.

Comment: you could subclass list.

Answer (score 2):

Appropriate answer was already mentioned in comments. Still, if you don't want to bother with subclasses, you can write implicit for this fun:

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> case class ListFilter[T](list: List[T]) {
   def filterOrSelf(f: T => Boolean) = list.filter(f) match {
      case Nil => list 
      case l => l
   }
}
defined class ListFilter

scala> implicit def toListFilter[T](list: List[T]) = ListFilter(list)
toListFilter: [T](list: List[T])ListFilter[T]

scala> l.filterOrSelf(_ == 4)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.filterOrSelf(_ == 3)
res1: List[Int] = List(3)
```